# How to get a minimum value by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame looks like this

```
library(dplyr)
test.df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,3,3,3,3),
                      date=c("2016-02-13","2016-06-01",
                             "2016-09-01","2015-08-02",
                             "2015-09-21","2016-12-01",
                             "2017-02-11"))

test.df$date <- as.Date(test.df$date,format='%Y-%m-%d')

id    date
1   2016-02-13          
1   2016-06-01          
1   2016-09-01          
3   2015-08-02          
3   2015-09-21          
3   2016-12-01          
3   2017-02-11
```

And I want to create a new variable `first.login` to get first date of each `id`. The output will look like this

```
id    date      first.login
1   2016-02-13  2016-02-13
1   2016-06-01  2016-02-13      
1   2016-09-01  2016-02-13      
3   2015-08-02  2015-08-02      
3   2015-09-21  2015-08-02      
3   2016-12-01  2015-08-02      
3   2017-02-11  2015-08-02
```

I try to use code like this

```
new.df <- test.df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(first.log = min(date))
```

But this gives the result that extracts earliest date for the whole data frame, not within each ID group.

```
id    date      first.login
1   2016-02-13  2015-08-02
1   2016-06-01  2015-08-02      
1   2016-09-01  2015-08-02      
3   2015-08-02  2015-08-02      
3   2015-09-21  2015-08-02      
3   2016-12-01  2015-08-02      
3   2017-02-11  2015-08-02
```

This shouldn't be a tricky task, but I was wondering what mistake did I make? How can I get the earliest within each `id` group?

Update:
I've tried to use `summarize` before,

```
new.df <- test.df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(first.login = min(date))
```

but it returns a single row and column.

```
first.log
2015-08-02
```

It turns that there's nothing wrong with these codes; I just need to specify `dplyr::mutate` in it.

Comment: I think you need to use  summarize.

Comment: I think that code should work. Note your example has a column header `first.login` while your code has `first.log =` .

Comment: That's what I thought, but it only returns a single column and single row `first.log  2015-08-02`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step R base solution:

```
# renaming for easy handle
x <- test.df$date
g <- test.df$id
# getting min
split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), min)
# merging
test.df$first.login <- do.call("c", split(x, g))
#printting result
test.df
  id       date first.login
1  1 2016-02-13  2016-02-13
2  1 2016-06-01  2016-02-13
3  1 2016-09-01  2016-02-13
4  3 2015-08-02  2015-08-02
5  3 2015-09-21  2015-08-02
6  3 2016-12-01  2015-08-02
7  3 2017-02-11  2015-08-02
```

Actually this is how `ave` Works inside

Answer (score 6):

You want to use summarize instead of mutate

```
new.df <- test.df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(first.log = min(date))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, I've tried but it only returns a single column and single row `first.log 2015-08-02`.

Comment: Agree. Not good if you want to keep all the data

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you need one result per row, and not just one value per group, you should use base R function `ave`.

```
test.df$first.login <- ave(test.df$date, test.df$id, FUN = min)
test.df
#  id       date first.login
#1  1 2016-02-13  2016-02-13
#2  1 2016-06-01  2016-02-13
#3  1 2016-09-01  2016-02-13
#4  3 2015-08-02  2015-08-02
#5  3 2015-09-21  2015-08-02
#6  3 2016-12-01  2015-08-02
#7  3 2017-02-11  2015-08-02
```