# Create new columns for certain column entries in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, data-manipulation

Imagine a snippet of the follow data frame:

```
       ID        ActivityName     Time         Type    Shape 
1       1             Request    0.000       Type_1      767           
2       1             Request  600.000       Type_1      767           
3       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376           
4       1               Start  600.000       Type_1     1376  
5       1               Delay 2962.295       Type_1     1022         
6       1 Schedule Activities  600.000       Type_1       15           
7       1 Schedule Activities 2062.295       Type_1       15
```

What I'm trying to do is to create two new columns based on the repeating entries in `ActivityName`.

Specifically, I want to combine two subsequent rows for the same activity into one row with a start and end timestamp (from `Time`, in seconds).

Given that not all entries in `ActivityName` have a matching second entry (however, max two consecutive entries are identical), I would also like to *delete* such rows, such as `Delay` in this case.

It should then look something like:

```
       ID        ActivityName  StartTime   EndTime      Type    Shape 
1       1             Request  0.000       600.000      Type_1  767           
2       1               Start  600.000     600.000      Type_1  1375
3       1 Schedule Activities  600.000     2062.295     Type_1  15
```

All categories in `ActivityName` occur many times in that column. I don't hope to compare their associated `Time` across the whole column, bur rather only those who have two consecutive identical occurrences.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You could use the process here to group by ID, ActivityName, Type, and Shape and summarize StartTime = min(Time) and EndTime = max(Time): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178153/how-to-get-a-minimum-value-by-group

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(ID, ActivityName, Type, Shape) %>%
  summarise(
    StartTime = min(Time),
    EndTime = max(Time),
    n = n() 
  ) %>% 
  filter(n > 1) %>% 
  select(-n)`?

Comment: @Alex +1 for a well explained question, especially for a new user. Next time, you can do even better by using the `dput` function. @JasonAizkalns shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: @DanChaltiel - feels like a duplicate if this is a legit answer, awaiting confirmation from Alex.

Comment: Hurray @JasonAizkalns, that did the trick. Thanks everyone